# How to instruct Google to ignore URLs with given suffix/parameter?

Tags: seo, url, google-index

Hi there I need to temporarily instruct Google to exclude from indexing all URLs that contain the following suffix: `?lang=it`
How can I achieve this?

Comment: What options have you considered?

Comment: Asking here on prowebmasters! Now seriously... :-) I have no idea! Apache rewrite condition? Or?

Comment: I'd think we would have answered this one before, but I can't find a duplicate.

Comment: To be clear, do you really mean indexing (= Googlebot may still *crawl* the pages), or do you mean crawling (= Googlebot may still *index* the pages)? And should the solution *only* work for Google Search, not also other search engines?

Comment: @Riccardo My point is — hopefully you've searched Google and made some attempt to figure it out before asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Googlebot how to handle your site's parameters in search console here:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/crawl-url-parameters?hl=en&siteUrl=

Simplly click "add parameter" and then add `lang=it`. Select yes from the dropdown menu. From there you can tell Googlebot not to index pages with that parameter in your URL.

Comment: I am not sure, what is OP mean by exclude...He is facing duplicate content issue? or he just don't want to index those it lang pages? or don't want to allowed Googlebot at all.